# Mysql sum group by performance 9M records

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ~ 9 million records

Structure

```
 id                           int PK AI
 pa_id                        int
 cha_id                       smallint
 cha_level                    tinyint
 cha_points                   mediumint
 cha_points_till              smallint
 cha_points_from              medium
 cha_points_date              datetime
```

My query

```
select max(cha_points) as highest,cha_id,count(id) as entry_count,
sum(cha_points) as total_points 
          from playeraccounts_cha_masteries 
          group by cha_id 
          order by total_points desc
```

My indexes

```
playeraccounts_cha_masteries 0 PRIMARY    1 id         A 9058483 NULL NULL BTREE
playeraccounts_cha_masteries 1 cha_id     1 cha_id     A       9 NULL NULL BTREE
playeraccounts_cha_masteries 1 pa_id      1 pa_id      A  156270 NULL NULL BTREE
playeraccounts_cha_masteries 1 cha_points 1 cha_points A  166100 NULL NULL BTREE
```

The index on pa_id has its use in a different query.

Explain

```
id select_type table partitions  type  possible_keys     key key_len  ref    rows   filterd    Extra
 1      simple     m       null range PRIMARY,cha_id PRIMARY       4 NULL 9164555    100.00    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Is there any i can speed up the query still?

Comment: have you use partition ?

Comment: As it's a full table lookup won't that not use the effect of partitioning?

Comment: Pls add the result of explain.

Comment: Also, how often do you need to run this query? You may want to consider using a separate table to hold these data which you can update using triggers or by executing the above query periodically only to refresh the snapshot.

Comment: Added the explain. It should run when a user requests the page bascially. Users can update their records ( identifed to them with pa_id ) every 3 days

Comment: Try to create a composite index on cha_id and cha_points fields, change count(id) to count(*) or count(cha_id), and test again. You may have to play with the order of fields in the index. Check with explain if the covering index is used.

Comment: When running an EXPLAIN on a single table query, I think it's nice to use "\G" instead of ";"

Comment: Adding the comp index + count(cha_id )  dropped it down to 2.5 seconds from the orginal 10 seconds.. Seeing as the table can get 10 times bigger. Its probably easier to use the snapshot method

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. Speed up the existing query

Create a composite index on cha_id and cha_points fields, change count(id) to count(*) or count(cha_id), and test again. You may have to play with the order of fields in the index. Check with explain if the covering index is used.

By changing count(id) to count(*) or count(cha_id) you eliminate the need to check the id column. Since you use that count to return the number of records within each cha_id group, it is safe to replace the reference to id field with * or cha_id.

Creating a composite index on cha_id and cha_points fields will result in a covering index, meaning all fields required by the query is in a single index, so the query does not have to scan the entire table.

2. Create a separate statistics table and update it with triggers

Create a separate statistics table for playeraccounts_cha_masteries. You can use triggers to update counts, maximums, and totals. The page would query the statistics table instead of the playeraccounts_cha_masteries table. This solution may slow inserts / updates / deletes down, since each data modification transaction has to be serialised, so that the statistics table is properly updated.

3. Create a separate statistics table and update it periodically

Create a separate statistics table, but instead of using triggers to keep it constantly updated, use scheduled job (OS or mysql level) to periodically update the table with the latest statistics. This would mean that the stats will be out of sync for a while, but this may be a reasonable compromise, if an acceptable refresh period can be found.

You can even take this approach one step further, and instead of generating a separate statistics table, you can generate a static html file with appropriate expiry set in its headers with the statistics. This way the server has only to serve the static file for the statistics.

Comment: I've decided to use the separate table approach which also allows me have a timeline kind of things in relation to the points.